# Why `.` is automatically added to gcc header searching paths if C_INCLUDE_PATH contains a trailing `:`

Tags: gcc

Actually I got this problem when compiling gcc-4.7.2. But I can simply reproduce the problem as follows:

I have a simple source file hello.c for test. Its content is simply a include directive:

```
#include "hello.h"
```

In bash, I first run the following command:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/dwang/local/include:
```

Then I run:

```
gcc -v -E hello.c
```

It outputs the searching paths:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/home/dwang/local/include
/export/scratch/packages/include/
.
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
[...]
```

Then if I remove the trailing `:` from `C_INCLUDE_PATH`:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/dwang/local/include
```

The searching paths are:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/home/dwang/local/include
/export/scratch/packages/include/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
[...]
```

It seems that if there is a trailing `:` in `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `.` will be automatically added. Is this a feature or a bug of gcc?

How this breaks my gcc compilation is stated here: [Error Compiling gcc-4.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350488/error-compiling-gcc-4-7-2/14351132)

Compiler: gcc-4.6.1

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

Thanks.

Comment: Why someone downvoted this question? Any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a feature of gcc, as documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html)

quoting from the docs:

> In all these variables, an empty element instructs the compiler to search its current working directory. Empty elements can appear at the beginning or end of a path. For instance, if the value of CPATH is :/special/include, that has the same effect as `-I. -I/special/include'.